# Connect via perl:DBI to MariaDB takes more than 9 minutes

Tags: mariadb, connection

I am running a perl script to update a table in a MariaDB. For a long time, this worked  without any problems. But since some system upgrade, the connect to the MariaDB in the same computer takes more than 9 minutes.

- Connect to a mySql database on a remote computer via perl:  no problem.
- Connect to MariaDB on local computer via MySqlWorkbench: takes too long to connect
- Connect to MariaDB on local computer via mysql-connector-java: no problem
  Connect call is

perl:DBI should connect to MariaDB within seconds.

```
     my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$schema;host=$host", $user, $passwd,
                  {RaiseError => 0 }
                   ) || die "ERROR: Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems not to be with MariaDB but rather with leap network configuration. ping on the server shows that an ipv6 address is used, but the system does not respond. Disabling ipv6 shows an ipv4 address for ping, and the problem with MariaDB is resolved. There remains the question why ping does not work with an active ipv6, but that is an other problem.